# InnoSetup Rename Install Folder and Run Exe

Tags: inno-setup, pascal

I am creating a patch installer using InnoSetup.

After the installation, I want InnoSetup to rename the folder in Program Files (as you can see in the `[Code]` section below.

This works fine. But then, at the end of the installation, it prompts if I want to run the app. When yes is selected - it looks for the exe file in the old path. It makes sense because that is what is in the `{app}` variable.

So my question, is how can I make the `[Run]` section look at the new renamed path?

Please note that I have `UsePreviousAppDir=yes` set to true and should stay set to true.

Here are related parameters for my InnoSetup:

```
[Setup]
UsePreviousAppDir=yes

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent

[Code]
{ ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// }
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  RenameFile(ExpandConstant('{app}'), ExpandConstant('..\{app}') + ExpandConstant('{#MyAppName}') + ' ' + ExpandConstant('{#MyAppVersion}'))
end;
```

UPDATE:
Was able to make it work now. Seems my path above is incorrect. Answer has been posted below.

Comment: Your code is not correct. 1) Do not ever do any modifications to the user's machine in `InitializeWizard` – that occurs even before the user confirms he/she want to install anything. 2) `ExpandConstant('..\{app}') + ExpandConstant('{#MyAppName}') + ' ' + ExpandConstant('{#MyAppVersion}')` resolves to something like `..\C:\Program Files\MyAppMyApp 1.2.3` – That does not look like a correct path to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to make it work now.

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\..\{#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent

[Code]
{ ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// }
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if (CurStep=ssPostInstall) then
  begin
    RenameFile(ExpandConstant('{app}'), ExpandConstant('{app}\..\{#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}'))
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This looks much better than what you have posted in the question.

Comment: You can improve it by factoring out the path definition, not to repeat it: `#define NewAppPath "{app}\..\"+MyAppName+" "+MyAppVersion` and then `Filename: "{#NewAppPath}\{#MyAppExeName}"` and `ExpandConstant('{#NewAppPath}')`

Comment: Haha yeah, my mind got topsy turvy for a bit. Sorted it out now. Thanks!

Comment: Nice, thanks for the optimized solution @MartinPrikryl! Trying it out now!